# jekyll not generating posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I am using the [bloggy gem](https://github.com/zbruhnke/bloggy) to put a jekyll blog within my current rails app.  Basically, you have a normal jekyll build but then you put your files in the config/jekyll directory and generate files into the public/blog directory.

However, when I run `jekyll build`, none of my posts are generated.

Here is the config file:

```
markdown: rdiscount
permalink: /:title.html
destination: ../../public/blog
exclude:
  - Rakefile
  - Gemfile
  - .gitignore
```

Here is my directory structure within config/jekyll

```
./_config.yml
./_layouts
./_layouts/default.html
./_layouts/page.html
./_layouts/post.html
./_posts
./_posts/2013-06-07-dear-nsa.md
./_posts/2013-06-07-wut.markdown
./atom.xml
./css
./css/screen.css
./css/syntax.css
./index.html
```

And here is the generated directory structure with public/blog

```
./atom.xml
./css
./css/screen.css
./css/syntax.css
./index.html
```

A clue I've come up with:  if I specify the source as the _posts, it will generate html versions of my posts into public/blog... but will not include the css or index page.

Comment: Just to be sure: did you remember to put YAML front matter on the posts?

Comment: I did, but while checking I noticed the `published: false` option.  Changing that to true fixed it.  *facepalm*